# How to avoid sublime text 2 freezing

Tags: garbage-collection, sublimetext2

Sublime text 2 is freezing from time to time, when I have many selections in large files. After a while it continues. I am on windows 2008.

For example it happens when I hit ctrl-d many times or even keep it pressed to add many selections. It adds selections, then stops, and after a while continues adding selections.

I suspect this is due to garbage collection.

Is there a way to avoid this or make the freeze period shorter? Maybe give it more memory, or even better less memory so gc is more frequent but much shorter.

Or maybe this is some sort of swapping or missing or wrong temp file config.

What is the reason and is there a good solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text 3 may freeze too. Plugins can cause that.

#### First thing

...you may want to do is run command `CTRL + SHIFT + P` -> `Plugin Development: Profile Events`. You will get a list of events which different plugins are listening to and time it taken for them to process the event.

Give special attention to **on_modified** event. Quote from [sublime docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#responding-to-events):

> Expensive operations in event listeners can cause Sublime Text to
>   become unresponsive, especially in events triggered frequently, like
>   `on_modified()` and `on_selection_modified()`. Be careful of how much work
>   is done in these and don’t implement events you don’t need, even if
>   they just `pass`.

This was my case: a plugin was meticulously processing every on_modified event which resulted in overflowing the thread queue and freezing ST.

#### Also

... don't forget that Sublime Text has a console where you sometimes can find useful messages and tracebacks. To reveal console use a key binding **CTRL+`**. Working for a while with your eye on the console may help you get the idea if something is going on wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It recently starting freezing for me too, each time I'd re-focus on code in a Sublime window, whether that be alt-tabbing or even searching the *command palette*!

What fixed it up quickly for me was [Reverting to a Freshly Installed State](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html), then restoring those folders.

Update: It turned out to be [Git Conflict Resolver](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git%20Conflict%20Resolver)
, perfectly responsive after disabling.

Answer (score -1):

This question is old, and the issue did not occur with later versions anymore.

So I suspect it was fixed at some point.

If you still experience freezing in sublime text try the following:

- Find out what version you are running and try switching to the latest stable version.
- See if the freezing could be an operating system issue. This could be indicated by not only sublime text but at the same time all other applications freezing.

If you have a different solution or explanation why not add it here for reference.

I still believe the underlying reason could have been a garbage colletion (read at wikipedia about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))) within the application.

Comment: I had freezes caused by having a (small) text file open in the background which was constantly being re-written by another application.